# Remote Alarm Monitoring of Adobe Flash Media Encoder

Tags: adobe

We're currently running 8 Adobe Flash Media Encoder servers which are streaming content to a CDN (Limelight). I've been trying to figure out a way of getting an alarm (SNMP, email, or otherwise) out of the damn things when they stop streaming, switch to backup url or have any other issues. The stream output from Limelight is checked fairly frequently by an operator but it would be nice to get on top of failures a little quicker.

The only option I've thought of so far is a frequent read of the log file and putting together a script to make sense of it but I'm hoping there's a more reliable way, just wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since opening up the rtmp spec I'd expect a tiny rtmp tester to be written by someone somewhere-- we (@viddler) were working on one a while back when we were running FMS -- eventually we swtiched to wowza media server and the crashes went away, so dev on this monitor was deprioritized.